Notepad ++ not saving ftp/sftp remote files
i usually use notepad++ for coding , from last 3 days i am receiving this issue that notepad++ is not saving ftp files suddenly shows failed. i am using hostgator shared hosting and i have 2 accounts with hostgator , 1 account's files are saving but other account has issue , i contacted hostgator support they said if it is saving/uploading by using cpanel then its not our issue and files upload and save directly from cpanel file editor is working but if it is notepad++ issue then why it is working with an other hostgator account but not this one, files permission are also same . i removed notepad cache, and also downgraded NP version still same, currently i am using 8.6 version of np++
NotepaD++ file save issue , changed version but still same
